# Windows program to communicate with Virtualbox

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, server, virtualbox

I am wondering if it is possible to write a program on Windows that communicates with a program within a Linux Virtualbox on the same machine.  If this is possible, what is the best approach to doing this?  Is there a way to do this without using the internet to communicate?

I found [instructions showing how you could potentially use SSH](http://wiredrevolution.com/virtualbox/setup-ssh-access-between-virtualbox-host-and-guest-vms), but I have never tried doing this before, so I do not know if using SSH to communicate would be the best option.

Comment: Yes ssh will work. There are many other ways (e.g. even a shared file would work). Your question is thus too broad.

Answer (score 2):

I was going to put this as a comment to a very vague question, but then it got too long.

It depends what you mean by *"communicate"*....

- If the Windows machine should start a program on the Linux VM, you probably want `plink.exe` - see [here](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html).
- If you want to transfer whole files, you probably want `scp` or `FTP` or `FileZilla` - see [here](https://filezilla-project.org).
- If you want to send small messages occasionally, maybe `netcat`, also known as `nc` - see Netcat Cheatsheet [here](https://www.sans.org/security-resources/sec560/netcat_cheat_sheet_v1.pdf).
- If you want full-on, high speed, continuous messages, maybe sockets or some messaging protocol like `mqtt`.
- If you want to share **data structures**, like lists, queues or sets, you could allow both Windows and the Linux machine to access a shared **Redis** database - see [here](https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro).
- Or maybe it is enough to share a filesystem between the two machines - in which case you can make a *Shared Folder* in VirtualBox on your host and the VM can just mount that and read/write it. See diagram:

[image]